# How reverse animation with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i'm stuck in something here.

Several elements of the site that I'm doing will have a slideIn and slideout effect left or right (determined by me). So I created this piece of code that is helping me to achieve what I want, if not for one problem: the reverse animation is not working at all.

All the javascript code:

```
+ function($) {
  var ScrollAnimation = function(element) {
    var self = this;
    self.element = element;
    self.initial = self.element.data('animation-time')[0];
    self.final = self.element.data('animation-time')[1];
    self.animation = self.element.data('animation-type');
    self.position = self.element.data('animation-position');

    $('.container').scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (self.initial < scroll && self.final > scroll) {
        self.animate();
      }
      else if (self.final < scroll || self.initial > scroll) {
        self.disanimate();
      }
    });
  };

  ScrollAnimation.prototype.animate = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.element.css('display', 'inline-block');

    if (self.position === 'right') {
      self.element.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: '0px'
      }, 500);
    }
    else if (self.position === 'left') {
      self.element.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '0px'
      }, 500);
    }
  };

  ScrollAnimation.prototype.disanimate = function() {
    var self = this;

    if (self.animation === 'fade') {
      self.element.fadeOut(500);
    }
    else if (self.animation === 'slide') {
      self.element.css('display', 'none');

      if (self.position === 'right') {
        self.element.css('right', '245px');
      }
      else if (self.position === 'left') {
        self.element.animate({
          opacity: 0,
          left: '245px'
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  };

  ScrollAnimation.prototype.addClass = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.element.addClass('is_active');
  };

  ScrollAnimation.prototype.removeClass = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.element.removeClass('is_active');
  };

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('[data-animation-time]').each(function() {
      var animation = $(this);
      animation = new ScrollAnimation(animation);
    });
  });

}(jQuery);
```

Explanation:

```
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('[data-animation-time]').each(function() {
      var animation = $(this);
      animation = new ScrollAnimation(animation);
    });
  });
```

When the window loads, it looks for all the elements that has the date-time animation attribute and create an instance of ScrollAnimation.

```
  var ScrollAnimation = function(element) {
    var self = this;
    self.element = element;
    self.initial = self.element.data('animation-time')[0];
    self.final = self.element.data('animation-time')[1];
    self.animation = self.element.data('animation-type');
    self.position = self.element.data('animation-position');

    $('.container').scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (self.initial < scroll && self.final > scroll) {
        self.animate();
      }
      else if (self.final < scroll || self.initial > scroll) {
        /*self.disanimate();*/
      }
    });
  };
```

Now every time the Scroll of .container reach the initial time, the animation happens .. And if the Scroll of .container reach the final time, the animation should reverse

Animate:

```
  ScrollAnimation.prototype.animate = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.element.css('display', 'inline-block');

    if (self.position === 'right') {
      self.element.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: '0px'
      }, 500);
    }
    else if (self.position === 'left') {
      self.element.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '0px'
      }, 500);
    }
  };
```

Desanimate:

```
  ScrollAnimation.prototype.animate = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.element.css('display', 'inline-block');

    if (self.position === 'right') {
      self.element.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: '0px'
      }, 500);
    }
    else if (self.position === 'left') {
      self.element.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '0px'
      }, 500);
    }
  };
```

But the desanimate is not working, only the animate. I really don't know what is the problem here, a hand will be very very appreciated...

Codepen with an working code: http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/yymNRX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your codepen working, I think you'll find what is missing on your source code from it.

The link : http://codepen.io/benjaminchanudet/pen/YPmydG

What I did :

- HTML side : I just added two elements with the same `data-animation-time` attributes than your list elements to see if it was really working.
- CSS : I put the .list `position` to `fixed` instead of `absolute`. `absolute` made the list follow the scrolling, so we couldn't see the effect.
- Javascript : I added a boolean attribute `shown`. The scroll event is triggered *a lot* by browser. The boolean avoids the queueing of `animate`. I disabled also the line `self.element.css('display','none');` that didn't let a chance for the animation to happen.

I hope this help for you real code. :)

Comment: i need to say.. you're a genius Ben! haha